# How can I skip rewriting files of a specific type only if they exist, and if not, use a custom error handler?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` which does most of what I would like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now, instead of the generic not found message on the file types, I would like to designate custom error handlers for them, so I tried to append the following :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [R=404,L]
```

However, when the file is not found, it still isn't passing to my `controller.php` file.

How can I modify this so that this line also ensures that specific file requested, of that type exists :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
```

---

UPDATE :

The following works, but seems to have trouble when the missing image is in a virtual sub path

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=error&rewritten=1&missing=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

## main app path (working as intended)

[image: working]

## sub path - not passing all parameters

[image: subpath]

For demonstration, the `controller.php` file can be as follows :

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

---

## Solution (working)

---

Posting the full `.htaccess` file here which is the result of combining the solution from [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36660549/3504007) with the solution from [anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36660723/3504007) .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=error&rewritten=1&missing=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The rewrite condition to exclude images, javascript, etc., from rewriting needed `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` to be changed to `%{REQUEST_URI}`, where the final rewrite rule after the `!-f` (file does not exist) check, needed the `R=404` removed.

While I am unsure as to why this works, or why checking the physical file on the initial rewrite condition caused issues with the final rewrite rule, it does work. It is times like this where awarding (or splitting the award) for the solution merits such a feature, as neither solution by itself resolved the issue, however both together complimented each other nicely, resulting in a final full working solution to this problem :)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` skips rewriting any existing file. What is the full URL for which you're getting this problem?

Comment: @anubhava - i am not looking to skip all files.  Only specific files, and without specifically excluding folders, so this is a soft structure.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting with a 4XX or 5XX status code will cause HTTPd to display an error page rather than rewrite the request. You will need to detect the absence in `controller.php` (or pass such as an argument) and emit the error code there.

Comment: I changed it, and it seems to work, but only from the main folder. subfolders still rewrite, but the additional params i am setting in htaccess aren't being passed along.  it's very strange.

Comment: Added demonstration of my implementation of this suggestion, and the results.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
```

to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$ [NC]
```

Using `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` ensures that existing file check is not done and any request ending in above extensions will be skipped.

---

**Update:** After reading your final edit it became more clear what you're trying to do.

In your final working solution you have a **redundant rule** to handle non-existing-files for 2 reasons:

1. Client will not see all important `404` status for some non-existing file
2. `ErrorDocument` is the right directive to handle this than rewrite rule.

You can have your .htaccess as:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /controller.php?page=error&rewritten=1
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|png|bmp|gif|css|js|map|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ controller.php?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` inside `controller.php` will give you the requesting URI that has triggered 404.

Comment: swapping that line out, solved the new problem that cropped up.  your answer and Ignacio's answer combined resolved the problem.

Comment: Indeed you do need to place `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` at top of your .htaccess

Comment: Nein, this combination results in no actual 404's, so I have to emulate them.    Posting the full working .htaccess in the question, so you guys can see what the deal was.  It's actually pretty cool.  Just need to set the appropriate HTTP/1.x header when displaying the custom pages so google doesn't freak out if spidering